# How to design the table in awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

My input file is file1

```
count  month

505  Apr-2010 
252  Mar-2010 
426  Feb-2010 
201  Jan-2010 
211  Dec-2009
```

Same file I want the output like this below

```
+-------+----------+
| count | month    |
+-------+----------+
|   505 | Apr-2010 |
|   252 | Mar-2010 |
|   426 | Feb-2010 |
|   201 | Jan-2010 |
|   211 | Dec-2009 |
+-------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for your input:

```
BEGIN {
     n=0
     sep="+-------+----------+"
}
{
    if (/^$/) {
        print sep
    } else if (n==0) {
        print sep
        print "| "$1" | "$2"    |"
    } else {
        print "|   "$1" | "$2" |"
    }
    n++
}
END {
    print sep
}
```

It doesn't do any automatic alignment so it will break if any of the fields increase in width. Take a look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123438/align-columns-right) for automatic alignment.

Comment: thnk u its working.. @Evan teitelman